# The best solution for designing a automation database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, automation

What is the best way to implement information with a one to many relationship in a large automation system located on a local server?
Getting a report and record it is the most important point of the system.

**For example**, consider a travel agency that has several guides that perform one tour in week. To record the agency's information, best way is use three tables, one to store the agency's information and one to store personalized guide information and one to store relationship(one to many) **but** whit this way, changing the person's guide information that will perform a tour this week will change, so the report received from the system will also change. **Another method** of storing is to use a table, in which the agency's information is stored, and the person's information is also stored in a column in the json format.For example, consider the following table.

**Agency Table:**
agency_id | name | phone_number | address | **guides_details** (That information stored in this column is stored in json format like name, mobile and ....)

**Now my question is:**
Given the fact that the storage size for the project is not important (due to the use on the local server), is the second method suitable for large-scale information storage (archive)? Or, if there's another way to archive it, teach me please.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, its a bad practice to store JSON data in a table if it can be expressed in a tabular format. The reason for this is because you would not be able to query those details in your database language with ease.

I would suggest the following tables:

#### Agency Table

agency_id | (any other static information)

#### Agency Details Table

agency_detail_id | **agency_id** | created_date | name | phone_number | address |  (any other changeable details)

#### Guide Table

guide_id | (any other static information)

#### Guide Details Table

guide_detail_id | **guide_id** | created_date | phone | email | (any other changeable details)

#### Tour Table

tour_id | name | date | **agency_detail_id** | **guide_detail_id**

**Reasoning:**

The details table for agency and guide will allow you to keep different versions of each agency and guide for different tours and will allow you to preserve the ability to link the records back to which agency or guide the tour belongs to even if the details are different.

We have broken the guide details up into a table so that it can easily be queried against.

Comment: tnx, yes this is best way, but with this way when update guide or agency data, history of the tour information will be change,

Comment: @MohamadMahdiRezaei I've updated the answer to solve what issue you are referring to.

Comment: Tnx again,The dificulty of the way you say is the timing of its coding. While method json is much less time consuming, does method json have other flaws besides the difficulty in searching? In terms of the speed of running the program and ...

Comment: @MohamadMahdiRezaei Other than not being able to query it in the database language, no there is no real drawback to JSON as a column value. The difficulty (in your case) with JSON as the guide details is it would be hard to determine if the same guide did multiple tours and find the tours which that single guide did. I'm solving that problem by having a guide table separate from the details. If that doesn't matter to you then I suppose you could store it as JSON. In terms of speed, processing JSON may be slower than queries using your database layer, but that depends on your setup.